# AngulatJS + UI-Router: Connection check on page entry

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I got a little Problem at the Moment:

Im building a new WebApp with different States. For this im using UI-Router.
Different States mean different URLs.
The Problem is the WebApp has to open a connection via Websocket to a server. If the connection is opened and the user navigate through the page there is no Problem. The Problem for me is the first "State" the user enters the WebApp.

Example URLs:

- ".../" -> open Connection -> State Home
- ".../#/Overview" -> open Connection -> State Overview
- ".../#/User/12" -> open Connection -> State User with resolve for User-Id 12

I hope you understand what I mean.

First i thought I do this with a resolve but then I thought okay i want the user to show the information"open Connection" during the process.
If I use mutiple resolves (my 3rd Example) it would also Display open Connection 
So I need some "State" in the middle which Jumps in and then navigate to the state the user opened

Comment: Bitte shcreiben Sie nur in Englisch.

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English only site. You'll probably find this question gets deleted unless you can translate it. In any case you'll get a much better response in English.

Comment: Sorry I tranlated it in english

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has a answer?
Or is there maybe a way to initialize the page/App before UI-Router starts to work?
So before any States would Start the WebApp should open the connection and if it fails go to State "X" if not UI-Router should just do his normal job